# How do you write a rolling "Case When" statment in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-science, data-analysis, analysis

Let's say I have a table called "means" that looks like this:

```
year    mean
1990    1.5 
1991    1.0  
1992    1.3  
1993    1.0
```

And I have a second table called "values" that looks like this:

```
year tag value
1990 A   0.25
1991 B   1.10
1992 C   2.32
1993 A   0.70
```

I want to create another column where if the value for a given year is greater than the mean for a given year, the value of that column should be "Greater". If it's less than the mean for a given year, it should be "Less" and if it's equal to the mean, it should be "Equal".

Essentially, I want to create a series of Case When statements that are indexed to the year given in the table.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Using keywords to name things is a very bad idea in any language and is to be avoided like the plague. Consider renaming the table from  “values” to something else.

Answer (score 0):

That'as a join with conditional logic:

```
select 
    v.*,
    case 
        when v.value > m.mean then 'Greater'
        when v.value < m.mean then 'Less'
        else 'Equal'
    end comp
from vals v
inner join means m on m.year = v.year
```

Note: this is called a case *expression*, not a case *statement* (the former is a conditional expression, while the latter is a control flow structure).